# How do i merge table index name using pandas in python?

Tags: python, pandas, prettytable

I want to set two columns with their index in a single index. But i can not merge table index. How could i merge table index using pandas or row python code?

I tried and get this https://ibb.co/7nZyxCM

Here is the sample code using PrettyTable https://ibb.co/Hh80LBJ

What i want to get : 
https://ibb.co/cQWf2Rz

Answer (score 1):

You can create the new MultiIndex (to be used for columns) e.g. from tuples:

```
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([
    ('August', 'Invoice'), ('August', 'Sells'),
    ('September', 'Invoice'), ('September', 'Sells'),
    ('Growth', '1'),  ('Growth', '2') ])
```

Then just set it as *columns* in your *df*:

```
df.columns = cols
```